# Activity doesn't finish

Tags: android, android-activity, countdowntimer

I have 3 activities(a,b and c). In activity a I have a countdowntimer which starts after some seconds activity b. In activity a the User can start activity c:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(a.this, c.class);
a.this.startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

with this code I want to finish the countdowntimer activity a and start c. Now the problem: When the user starts c, c starts but the countdown has not stoped and starts activity b when it has finished. Why? I have finsish the hole activity a - with the countdowntimer. I don't understand. I also tryed `onDestroy()`, but it doesn`t works.
My Countdowntimer:

```
new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000) {
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { }
  public void onFinish() { }
}.start();
```

Comment: how have you implemented the countdown timer?>

Comment: you should stop the timer on the onStop() function of activity a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class a extends Activity {
   CountDownTimer timer;

   public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
     // ..
     timer = new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000) {
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { }

       public void onFinish() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(a.this, b.class);
        a.this.startActivity(myIntent);           
       }
     }.start();
   }

   public void startActivityC()
   {
      timer.cancel();
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(a.this, c.class);
      a.this.startActivity(myIntent);      
   }   
}
```

Keep in mind that this is pseudocode and may have bugs/errors. Its simply intended to illustrate the technique rather than to be working code.

Comment: wher e i get the name of my countdown timer ?

Answer (score 0):

when you start the new activity with a.this.startActivity(myIntent); the 'a' activity stops and the finish() call is never executed. You should stop the timer before starting the 'c' activity.

Answer (score 0):

Override the onPause() function of activity a to stop the timer - maybe by checking a boolean variable set by whatever button or action starts the activity c.